# Workaround for bug with 0th <select> option in Mobile Safari on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

In Mobile Safari on the iPad, it seems that if there is no option selected on a `<select>` element, then the user cannot select the 0th option before selecting another one first (try it on http://jsfiddle.net/PJTKq/ on an iPad).

To be more specific:

1. Create a `<select>` element with two or more options.
2. Clear it by programmatically setting `selectedIndex = -1` or removing the `"selected"` attribute from all the `<option>` elements.
3. Tap the select element and choose the 0th option. The selected index won't change.
4. Tap the select element and choose another option, then tap it again and choose the 0th option. The selected index should change twice.

Does anyone know of a workaround (besides inserting an empty dummy option) that would allow moving directly from `selectedIndex` -1 to `selectedIndex` 0?

Comment: @Detect, you're right. It seems to be an iPad-only bug.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in iOS 5 (at least on the iPad 3).

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on an iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 11.2.6.  Works fine on the iPad now. This is happening when I have a ngModel added to a select (using Modern Angular) and the underlying value is empty and the select has no initial value selected.  The iPhone's scroll wheel which comes up at the bottom when the Select is focused thinks the first option is already selected, hence the user has to scroll off of the value and come back to it in order for it to be picked.  I have not found a good workaround yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>    
// with jQuery
var iPad = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i),
    select = "select";

if(iPad === true) {  
    $(select).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the bug is fixed, perhaps you could detect the user-agent and make `selectedIndex=0` the default for Mobile Safari.